# In the Movie "Her", when the OS is configuring Theodore's 'Profile', what's really going on?

Tags: analysis, her

First of all, I'd like to say that [*Her*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1798709/) was a terrific movie!

But given the scene when the OS was asking about *Theodore*'s relationship with his mother (as can be seen [here](http://dwd.x10.bz/demos/HTML5Video/her/index.html)), I'd like to know what was going on in the screenwriter's head, i.e. what was the hidden meaning behind this scene?

(I should add that I have an answer, and it's a doozie! It came to me in a dream. But I'd like to know what other people think about this scene.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I always thought it was the OS was initiating psychometric profile of Theodore, and the fact that it asks him about his mother was perhaps a humorous Freudian reference that compounds this.